# Diacritics doesn't incorrect font with @font-face

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, typography

I'm using Kiro and Lato font for some text, in my text I have Romanians diacritics.

Kiro has diacritics when I'm using in Photoshop and I included Lato like

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

But apparently diacritics show up in Times New Roman I think (check pic bellow)

Also I need to mention that in my  I have:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

[image]

Can someone explain me how to fix that, and why diacritics have the incorrect font?

Comment: Do these fonts contain exactly this specific diacritical character...?

Comment: Yes, in Photoshop diacritics works